# prestashop huge cache folder size

Tags: php, caching, prestashop

I have a shop with prestashop installed on it.
The cache folder size incrementally increases up-to 21gb+ every week & consumes heavy disk space.
What could be the reason behind this ?

In my settings - smarty cache is enabled
Recompile templates if the files have been updated is ticked.

Do I need to clear the cache in particular intervals ?
Is there any setting which I need to tweak inside the prestashop backend ?

Thanks.

Comment: Witch version of Prestashop are you using ? You're website is on a ubuntu server ? Do you have ssh access ?

Comment: I am using prestashop 1.5

Comment: You need to find out which templates are being cached the most. For example, if it turns out to be `blockcategories`, you may then make an overrides for its cache key, make its simpler (not differentiated by each user/group/category/product, etc.)

Comment: take a look here to reset cache with cron: 

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/343407-clear-smarty-cache-automatically

Answer (score 1):

Use this commands, to know which directory is getting huge:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 [project_root_path]/cache/
du -h --max-depth=1 [project_root_path]/cache/smarty
du -h --max-depth=1 [project_root_path]/cache/smarty/cache
```

You might have installed a module, which is handling cache inappropriately.

[This thread on Prestashop forum might be related](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/152104-smarty-cache-size-is-87-gigabyte/)

Comment: Thanks for such quick response,
Will disabling cache will fix this issue or will it face in slow web page loading ?

Comment: It's preferable not to disable cache. Did you find witch cache directory is too big ?